# JSON decode with PHP: Key started with @ sign

Tags: php, json

JSON is like

```
{
    "@http_status_code": 200,
    "@records_count": 200,
    "warnings": [],
    "query": { ... ...
```

In PHP

```
$data = json_decode($json_entry);
print $data->@http_status_code; //returns error
print $data->http_status_code; //returns nothing
```

How can I retrieve status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to get the json in form of array ..

```
$json_array     =  json_decode($data, true);
$required_data  = $data['required_key']
```

with reference to your particular problem .. you will get array as

```
Array
(
[@http_status_code] => 200
[@records_count] => 200
[warnings] => Array
    (
    )
   ....
)
```

so you can access you data as `$data['@http_status_code']`

Answer (score 3):

1) As **Object** way

```
$data = json_decode($json_entry);
print $data->{'@http_status_code'};
```

2) **OR** use as **array** way by passing second argument as `true` in `json_decode`

```
$data = json_decode($json_entry, true);
print $data['@http_status_code'];
```

Answer (score 1):

To access an object property that has funky characters in the name, quote the name and stick it in braces.

```
print $data->{'@http_status_code'};
```

Or, say `$data = json_decode($json_entry, true);` to get the data back as an array.

Answer (score 1):

PHP cwill give syntax error when you do this:

```
$data->@http_status_code;
```

it looks for `$http_status_code` variable which is not present

so in order to make this work you have to do this:

```
echo $data->{'@http_status_code'};
```

Comment: PHP won't even bother looking for `http_status_code`; it's a syntax error to have a `@` there, last i checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = json_decode($json_entry, true);
print $data["@http_status_code"];
```

Comment: You have to tell `json_decode` to return arrays in order for this to work.

Comment: this will only work when he does json_decode($json_entry,true)